# How and where is the OWIN pipeline run in ASP.net 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin

Given that the OWIN pipeline is currently tacked on to the traditional ASP.net pipeline, where and how is it integrated with ASP.net?

Is it implemented as an ASP.net handler/module?

My project has a class marked with the `OwinStartupAttribute` but what is looking for this attribute and whatever it is how is it given the opportunity to look for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all starts with the assembly Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb. The PreApplicationStartMethod attribute has been applied on this assembly, which means the code in this assembly, [PreApplicationStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.host.systemweb.preapplicationstart(v=vs.113).aspx) class to be exact runs even before  Application_Start. This class adds an  HttpModule  (OwinHttpModule)  into the IIS integrated ASP.NET pipeline. This HttpModule discovers the Startup class, and plugs the OWIN pipeline into the IIS pipeline. When the last OWIN middleware in the pipeline invokes next, IIS pipeline continues to run.